# how to make an argument in xml Required like width or height in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I made a custom view that needs an argument in XML to work properly. How can I make my custom attribute required like width and height value for every view in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any attribute for that. But you can throw an exception in your custom view if the value of the attribute is null.